Python Selenium DevTools "failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)"
I've been running some automations on a windows server (VM).
No problem for a year or two but now i got this problem when running it thru cmd promt.

ERROR: Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools) (Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.69) Stacktrace:

The chrome version and chromedriver is the same (using the newest selenium so it auto downloads).
Somebody that had simular problems?
I tried to change options for the chrome service in python.
Reboot
Pip upgrade all packages
Works fine when i run it thru vscode
EDIT:
What is different from the java case is that this happends live for me, not sleep mode or anything.
I tried all the solutions in the javacase but none of them works for me.
Sometimes i cant even start the automation with out getting the error.

Please check the process list when this error message comes out. It looks like that your chrome has not been started successfully by selenium, or killed by some reasons.
